# Keep duplicates in matches in two data structures

Tags: python-3.x, list, match, list-comprehension

Create a new data structure of matching items in two input data structures.

I would like to use a list comprehension as I am learning about them.
I tried 'dict' and 'set' as the new data structure for the matches. Unfortunately, both are designed for unique items.

```
todaysLoginList = ['Michael', 'Angelina', 'James', 'James'] #usernames logging in today
memberList = (['Madagascar', 'Michael'], ['Poland', 'Angelina'], ['USA', 'Alice'], ['Europe', 'James'])
[x[0] for x in memberList if x[1] in todaysLoginList]
```

**OUTPUT** from list comprehension

```
['Madagascar', 'Poland', 'Europe']
```

I would like

```
['Madagascar', 'Poland', 'Europe', 'Europe']
```

with the second 'Europe' duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier and cleaner to convert your membersList to a dict then you can look up location by  name (This assumes all usernames are unique since dict keys must be unique)

```py
todaysLoginList = ['Michael', 'Angelina', 'James', 'James'] #usernames logging in today
memberList = (['Madagascar', 'Michael'], 
              ['Poland', 'Angelina'], 
              ['USA', 'Alice'], 
              ['Europe', 'James']
)

#convert membersList to a dict
membersDict = {user: location for location, user in memberList}
print([membersDict[user] for user in todaysLoginList if user in membersDict])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['Madagascar', 'Poland', 'Europe', 'Europe']
```